# Getting SyntheticBaseEvent object instead of the simple Event when using React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm have this very simple React code:

```
const onSelectTournament = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
};
```

And this HTML:

```
<div onClick={onSelectTournament}></div>
```

But on console, instead of obtaining the `Event` object I'm getting this hell object:

```
    SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: 'onClick', _targetInst: null, type: 'click', nativeEvent: PointerEvent, target: div.tournamentsBoxDescription, …}
altKey: false
bubbles: true
button: 0
buttons: 0
cancelable: true
clientX: 382
clientY: 269
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
detail: 1
eventPhase: 3
getModifierState: ƒ modifierStateGetter(keyArg)
isDefaultPrevented: ƒ functionThatReturnsFalse()
isPropagationStopped: ƒ functionThatReturnsFalse()
isTrusted: true
metaKey: false
movementX: 0
movementY: 0
nativeEvent: PointerEvent {isTrusted: true, delegateTarget: document, pointerId: 1, width: 1, height: 1, …}
pageX: 382
pageY: 269
relatedTarget: null
screenX: 382
screenY: 373
shiftKey: false
target: div.tournamentsBoxDescription
timeStamp: 102788.7999997139
type: "click"
view: Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: '', location: Location, …}
_reactName: "onClick"
_targetInst: null
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Someone can help me?
I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SyntheticEvent` is an object that wraps the native `Event` in React, it gives you the same functionalities and more, like making sure you have the same behavior across browsers.

You can get the native `Event` by accessing the `nativeEvent` attribute of `SyntheticEvent`:

```js
e.nativeEvent
```

You can check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) if you wanna know more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are not calling a function twice at the same time. I had a similar challenge, turn out I was calling the same function from a single form at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React.MouseEvent type.

So, in your case:

```
const onSelectTournament = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => { ... }
```